# 2EDN mosfet driver burns out when connected to PWM signal

Tags: arduino, pwm, opto-isolator, mosfet-driver

Good day everyone, I am building a motor controller for a 250W DC motor.
Today I was testing a part of my design, but somehow the MOSFET driver did not work. The Arduino send a 50% square wave (4kHz) to the optocoupler. The optocoupler produced a clean square wave from 0V to 12V, just as expected. The driver, however, did not output such a signal. The output of the driver was around 0V, without any recognizable square wave or any wave whatsoever.
When I replaced the driver, I disconnected the output of the optocoupler from the input of the driver. I soldered a jumper to the input of the driver and manually connected it to 0V: Output of the driver was 0V. After that I connected the input manually to the 12V source: Output of the driver was 12V.
Being confident that the circuit would now work normally, I reconnected the square wave from the optocoupler to the MOSFET driver. Again, 0V on the output of the driver and a broken driver. 
Below will provide my circuit diagram.

Can someone please help me out?

parts:
Mosfet Driver: [2EDN8524FXTMA1](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-2EDN752x_2EDN852x-DS-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624cb7f111014d672f9fbb5142)
Optocoupler: TLP781F

**Thanks!!**[image: the circuit]

Comment: "MOSFETS" does not tell us much... what is over there....

Comment: Nothing right now, I disconnected the MOSFETs. but I wanted to show where they will be connected in the future when I get a satisfactory output on the driver

Comment: Sounds mysterious. Note that INB and ENB should probably be connected to either a logical high or low voltage rather than being left floating.

Comment: Maybe your 12V input rail is dipping below 8V and triggering the UVLO of your driver. If so, caps might help (as mentioned in answers).

Answer (score 1):

1. A opto-coupler here makes no sense since you are using a common ground on both sides anyway.

   Are you really sure that 12 V is a valid *input* to the FET gate driver?  You didn't link to the datasheet, so I didn't check.

   Gate drivers need good bypassing.  You don't have any bypass cap at all.  Doesn't the datasheet even point this out?  Most do.

Connect the digital output directly to the gate driver input.  Disconnect the output of the gate driver and verify everything is operating as it should.  This include checking the power supply during switching.

If you previously abused the gate driver, toss it, get a new one, and be more careful in the future.

Comment: Ok thanks I will change my design tomorrow, will let you know how it went

Answer (score 0):

An obvious problem is your choice of input/output resistors. If you look at the 4N25 data sheet, you'll see that the CTR for the 4N25 is guaranteed to be a minimum of 20%. With a 5volt/390 input, and a forward voltage of 1.5 volts, the input current will be about 9 mA. 20% of this (the output current) will be about 2 mA, and this will develop about .7 volts at the input of the driver. If, in fact, the CTR is better than 20%, you'll get a higher input voltage, but this is unlikely to provide enough input, and may even make matters worse by providing enough output to only turn the FET on partially. This in turn will cause overheating of the FET and may explain why yours burned out.

What you need to do is measure the gate voltage for both 0 and 4 volts at the Arduino, and verify that the gate is being driven to more than 10 volts. If not, check the driver input for input levels of 2.5 volts or more, with 3 being better. If the levels are too low, increase the value of the input resistor.